# Bokeh MultiChoice Onload with Pre-Selections

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh, bokehjs

I'm building a Bokeh app with a MultiChoice widget that will update a plot. The code works fine when I select multiple values, but I'm not able to implement a function to either (1) retain my desired selection(s) on startup, OR (2) load multiple values at once, such as in a list format.

Basically I have to manually enter my selections every time I load the app, which becomes cumbersome if I have a dataset with many values.

Is there a way to do this in the CustomJS?